# How to add buffer at top of chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cdf

I'm drawing a CDF chart using d3.js.
In the chart I have a symbol at 100th tick at the top of the chart.

The problem is that the symbol is getting cut-off.

I might not be able to post the entire code here posting only the part where the axis are drawn.
Attached is a screenshot of the top most part of the chart.

[image]

Below is the code to draw the axis.

```
const margin = {
  top: 5,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 60
};
this.x = this.addXScale(this.width - margin.left - margin.right);
this.y = this.addYScale(this.height - margin.top - margin.bottom);
this.yAxis = this.addLeftAxis(this.y , this.width - margin.left - margin.right, margin);
                                   
this.xAxis = this.addBottomAxis(this.x , this.height - (margin.top+0)  - margin.bottom, margin);

// Define svg component and attributes
const svg = this.chartService.drawChartArea(chartElement, this.height + this.xDelta,this.width, margin);
```

How do I add a buffer space at the top of the chart so that the symbol doesn't get cut off.

I tried adding a buffer space to x and y (margin.top+7) but on adding that the graph plot also goes outside the 100 line.

```
this.y = this.addYScale(this.height - (margin.top+7) - margin.bottom);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the range of the y-axis scale by increasing the maximum value by the amount of buffer space you want to add.

Example:

```
const margin = {
  top: 20, // increase top margin to create buffer space
  right: 20,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 60
};

// add buffer space to y-axis range
const yMax = d3.max(data, d => d.y) + bufferSpace; // replace `data` with your actual data array and `bufferSpace` with the amount of buffer space you want to add
this.y = this.addYScale(this.height - margin.top - margin.bottom, yMax);

// draw y-axis with updated scale
this.yAxis = this.addLeftAxis(this.y, this.width - margin.left - margin.right, margin);
```

To prevent the symbol from being cut off in the chart, you can make the chart taller by increasing the maximum value of the y-axis. You can control how much extra space is added at the top by adjusting the bufferSpace variable.